# How to get another table column in my table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two table. Records and Villas

**Records table**:

```
ID, VID (Villa ID), NAME, PRICE
```

**Villas table:**

```
ID, NAME (Villa NAME), PHOTOS etc.
```

I using this SQL:

```
SELECT records.id, villa_name AS (SELECT name FROM villas WHERE id = records.vid), records.name 
FROM records WHERE records.id = 5
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use JOIN here.

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, v.name
FROM records r
INNER JOIN villas v ON v.id = r.vid
WHERE records.id = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

`SELECT records.id, records.name AS record_name, villas.name AS villa_name FROM records INNER JOIN villas ON records.vid = villas.id WHERE records.id = 5`

Edit: Incorporated suggestion from Mark Bannister, below.

Comment: +1 Might be worth aliasing the `villas.name` to distinguish it from the `records.name`.